# Where to put a simple Class in an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok, this is possibly borderline-subjective, but I wonder where one would put a simple class that does something within an ASP.net MVC project? I mean a class like the [Base36 De/Encoder](http://www.stum.de/2008/10/20/base36-encoderdecoder-in-c/), that is neither Model nor Controller. Should this always go into a separate Class Library Assembly, or do such Classes have a place within the MVC Web Application project?

And yes, I know that it probably does not really matter, I'm just possibly a bit over careful to learn a new technology the "right" way from the beginning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I personally put such classes in some common "utils" assembly. Not only does it avoid junking up your MVC project, but such helper classes often find their way into other projects I work on.

Answer (score 4):

You should still have your separate projects where you include your own libraries, helpers and frameworks. You should still see the ASP.NET MVC project as a web project. You don't have to put all your business logic or web helpers in the Model folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [article](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/09/30/separate-assemblies-loose-coupling.aspx) Jeremy Miller wrote recently about separate assemblies.  Using the IoC pattern gets you loose coupling in a way that creating a lot of assemblies cannot.